# Template helper not returning contents of shared collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

In ./server/server.js, I have

```
if(Categories.find().count() === 0) {
    Categories.insert({name:'Fashion'});
    Categories.insert({name:'Travel'});
    Categories.insert({name:'Food'});
    Categories.insert({name:'Celebrities'});
}
```

In ./client/helpers.js, I have

```
Template.categories.helpers({
    Categories:function() {
        return Categories.find();
    },
});
```

In ./categories.html, I have

```
<template name='categories'>
  <ul>
    {{#each Categories}}
      <li id="categories"><a class="btn btn-default" href="/{{name}}">{{name}}</a></li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

In ./lib/collections.js, I have

```
Categories = new Mongo.Collection('categories');
```

When I check the contents of the categories db after running 'meteor mongo', the collections contains the categories defined in ./server/server.js, but the helper function in ./client/helpers.js returns nothing. When I add a function in this file that returns the count of Categories

```
Categories.find().count()
```

and display this on the template, it shows '0'. What's the problem? The client and server should be sharing the collection because the collection is initialized in the lib folder.

Comment: You need to publish the collection on the server, and subscribe to the publication on the client. Have you done that?

Comment: @JeremyS. I didn't think I had to because both the client and server have access to the collection through the lib directory...

Comment: They do have access to it which means they know _that_ `Categories` is defined, but your categories are only being inserted on the server. A definition of `Categories` is available on the client, but the client does not have access to the _data_ in that collection because it has not subscribed to it.

Comment: @herrshuster thanks, doing so worked

Comment: @JeremyS. Thanks for the tip. I didn't think to do it because the tutorial I'm following didn't have the code for it in their repo. It worked and I'm happy. Cheers!